# Export Excel range to TXT stop at empty cell

Tags: vba, excel, export-to-csv

Found following script

```
Sub saveText2()
Dim filename As String, lineText As String
Dim myrng As Range, i, j

filename = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\textfile-" & Format(Now, "ddmmyy-hhmmss") & ".txt"

Open filename For Output As #1

Set myrng = Range("Name")

For i = 1 To myrng.Rows.Count
    For j = 1 To myrng.Columns.Count
        lineText = IIf(j = 1, "", lineText & ",") & myrng.Cells(i, j)
    Next j
    Print #1, lineText
Next i
Close #1
End Sub
```

But I don´t seems to manage to stop the loop at first empty row.

I´ve tried to add a DO While myrng <> "" Loop but I don´t know where to apply the code.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it i the smartest way but I finally managedby doing this:

```
Sub saveText2()
Dim filename As String, lineText As String
Dim myrng As Range, i, j

filename = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\textfile-" & Format(Now, "ddmmyy-hhmmss") & ".txt"

Open filename For Output As #1

Set myrng = Range("A:B")

For i = 1 To myrng.Rows.Count
    For j = 1 To myrng.Columns.Count

    If IsEmpty(myrng.Cells(i, j)) = True Then
    Close #1
    Exit Sub
    End If

        lineText = IIf(j = 1, "", lineText & " ") & myrng.Cells(i, j)
    Next j
    Print #1, lineText
Next i
Close #1
End Sub
```